# Erro no PostgreSQL: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: portal "C_70" não existe

Tags: java, postgresql

Utilizamos uma aplicação Java Web com banco de dados Postgres para gerar os arquivos de Sped e no meio da geração do arquivo TXT estamos obtendo o erro abaixo. Esse `portal "C_70"` não se repete, necessariamente, e nem sempre é na mesma linha que ocorre o erro. Alguém já viu algo parecido e soube contornar?

```
Exception Stack Trace:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: portal "C_70" não existe
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.fetch(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2037)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.next(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1833)
        at wfr.database.PagedResultSet.next(SourceFile:191)
        at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl2.populate(SourceFile:752)
        at wfr.database.WFRResultSet.a(SourceFile:242)
        at wfr.database.WFRResultSet.next(SourceFile:220)
        at wfr.com.systems.system_sap.rules.WebrunFunctions.ebfSQLNext(WebrunFunctions.java:15523)
        at wfr.com.systems.system_sap.rules.SpedContabilBlocoI050.FlowRemark3(SpedContabilBlocoI050.java:395)
        at wfr.com.systems.system_sap.rules.SpedContabilBlocoI050.FlowRemark1(SpedContabilBlocoI050.java:382)
        at wfr.com.systems.system_sap.rules.SpedContabilBlocoI050.run(SpedContabilBlocoI050.java:344)
        at wfr.rules.WFRRule.start(SourceFile:761)
        at wfr.rules.WFRRule.callRule(SourceFile:681)
        at wfr.com.systems.system_sap.rules.Fis0001GerarSpedContabil.run(Fis0001GerarSpedContabil.java:179)
        at wfr.rules.WFRRule.start(SourceFile:761)
        at wfr.rules.WFRRule.callRule(SourceFile:681)
        at wfr.com.systems.system_sap.rules.Fis0000GerarSpedContabil.FlowSubRoutine1(Fis0000GerarSpedContabil.java:137)
        at wfr.com.systems.system_sap.rules.Fis0000GerarSpedContabil.run(Fis0000GerarSpedContabil.java:122)
        at wfr.rules.WFRRule.start(SourceFile:761)
        at wfr.rules.WFRRule.call(SourceFile:1823)
        at wfr.rules.WFRRule.call(SourceFile:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

P.S.: Infelizmente, eu não consigo postar o trecho de código no qual o erro ocorre, pois utilizamos uma ferramenta chamada Maker Studio que gera um código incompreensivel.

Comment: tente passar mais informações, com o que está aí fica complicado

Comment: Sem o código que trata a localização do tal "C_70" é impossível ajudar. O erro em si está bem claro.

Comment: @StatelessDev O problema maior é que encontramos pouquíssimas informações sobre esse erro. Ao mesmo tempo em que o erro está bem claro, ele não é muito bem conhecido, aparentemente. Enfim, conseguimos descobrir que ele ocorre no momento em que damos o "next()" no ResultSet e demos um jeito no próprio Maker Studio para que não ocorra mais. Obrigado!!

Comment: @FelipeJanser Se você achar que vale a pena, crie uma resposta para a sua própria pergunta e marque-a como correta, assim você conseguirá ajudar outros que, no futuro, passem pela mesma situação. Fico contente que tenha conseguido resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enfim, conseguimos descobrir que ele ocorre no momento em que damos o "next()" no ResultSet e demos um jeito na própria ferramenta Maker Studio para que o erro não ocorra mais.